# Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/newapropos/public_html/index.php on line 17

Tags: php, wordpress

This is what the error message says :

```
Warning: require(./wp-blog-header.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/newapropos/public_html/index.php on line 17

Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required './wp-blog-header.php' (include_path='.:/opt/alt/php73/usr/share/pear') in /home/newapropos/public_html/index.php on line 17
```

but I don't know what to change in the line 17 to fix?

Comment: What is version of PHP?

Answer (score 0):

I think check your php version should be greater than 7.4

Answer (score 0):

If you need to update your PHP version, [you can follow this guide](https://www.cloudbooklet.com/upgrade-php-version-to-php-7-4-on-ubuntu/). The update process also depends on if you use Ubuntu, Nginx, or apache, etc... What I shared here is for Ubuntu.